# Multiples instances of Bitronix / Atomikos for Spring Boot applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application has many datasources and **JTA** will manage my transactions, so I added into my Spring Boot application the **Bitronix** module. For record, I 
noticed it sets a JVM unique ID which by default is my ip address when the application is started.

If I have multiple Spring Boot applications running into the same server machine, will I get a conflict port telling that **Bitronix** is already running into another application? I mean Bitronix does use a default TCP port while is running, because **Atomikos** does it.

Another point, should be better having a unique JTA server for all applications or it's fine having a Bitronix server for each Spring Boot application.

***application.properties***

```
  #################
    ### Hibernate ###
    #################
    hibernate.show-sql=true
    hibernate.transaction.jta.enabled=true
    hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform
```

***Maven***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

***Java***

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagerConfig {
    public final static String TRANSACTION_MANAGER = "transactionManager";
    /**
     * Jboss JTA transaction manager
     * 
     * @return PlatformTransactionManager
     */
    @Bean(name = TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    @Conditional(JBossCondition.class)
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerByJta(final JndiTemplate jnditemplate) {
        // Get Jta from JEE server
        final JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManagerName("java:jboss/TransactionManager");
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransactionName("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        jtaTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        jtaTransactionManager.setJndiTemplate(jnditemplate);
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }
    /**
     * Bitronix JTA transaction manager
     * 
     * @return PlatformTransactionManager
     */
    @Bean(name = TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    @Conditional(SpringBootCondition.class)
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerByAtomikos() {
        // Get JTA from Bitronix
        final JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

**

Comment: I would recommend actually not to deploy bitronix, and all its libraries to jboss. And introduce multiple maven (or gradle) build profiles for spring standalone with bitronix provider, for jboss with container-provided, and for a start rely heavily on defaults of recent spring-boot.

Comment: my doudbt is if we can have many bitronix into same machine,  i will not run over jboss